# Ember.js insert after instead of append/To

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to add a template *after* an element in Ember.js but seems like appending is the only option right now. I'm using jQuery to traverse up to a clicked's element's parent then want to add the template `after` the parent.

Navigating like this: `$(this).closest("li").after()`

But Ember.js's appendTo don't work since I can only add the template inside the parent li.

I came across this pull request: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/627 which would implement an `insertAfter()` method but since this is not in the main branch I was wondering if there's any other way to do this?

Thanks,

G

Comment: Can I get a simple fiddler to get a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish?  There are different ways to skin a cat and I don't want to give inaccurate advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Not sure it's the best approach but it works. I basically add the template somewhere arbitrarily (in this case right after the link that is clicked) then after the element is inserted I move it using jQuery using $():

```
$(".commentReplyLink").live("click", function(){

    var new_reply_template = Ember.View.create({
      templateName: 'new_reply_template',
      didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().closest("li").after(this.$());
      }
    });

    new_reply_template.appendTo($(this).after());

});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/givp/tnQJf/28/

Answer (score -2):

It seems what you're looking for is the place() function.

http://uxebu.github.com/embedjs/docs/#place

```
// place(node, refNode, position)
embed.place("someNode", "anotherNode", "after");
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing ember.js with embed.js?